# How to disable TrueZIP key manager services?

Tags: java, truezip

I want to use TrueZIP 7.7 library in a server to uncompress user-uploaded archives. I don't plan to work with encrypted archives, and especially, since this is a server, I don't need a Swing popup to ask for a key. Yet when I created some simple test for unzipping a file, it failed with this error:

```
java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: de.schlichtherle.truezip.key.spi.KeyManagerService: Provider de.schlichtherle.truezip.fs.archive.zip.raes.PromptingKeyManagerService could not be instantiated: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: de/schlichtherle/truezip/swing/EnhancedPanel
        at java.util.ServiceLoader.fail(ServiceLoader.java:207)
        at java.util.ServiceLoader.access$100(ServiceLoader.java:164)
        at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.next(ServiceLoader.java:353)
        at java.util.ServiceLoader$1.next(ServiceLoader.java:421)
        at de.schlichtherle.truezip.key.sl.KeyManagerLocator$Boot.<clinit>(KeyManagerLocator.java:60)
        at de.schlichtherle.truezip.key.sl.KeyManagerLocator.get(KeyManagerLocator.java:41)
        at de.schlichtherle.truezip.key.AbstractKeyManagerProvider.get(AbstractKeyManagerProvider.java:22)
        at de.schlichtherle.truezip.fs.archive.zip.KeyController.getKeyManager(KeyController.java:62)
        at de.schlichtherle.truezip.fs.archive.zip.KeyController.sync(KeyController.java:129)
        at de.schlichtherle.truezip.fs.FsDecoratingController.sync(FsDecoratingController.java:131)
        at de.schlichtherle.truezip.fs.FsFalsePositiveArchiveController.sync(FsFalsePositiveArchiveController.java:480)
        at de.schlichtherle.truezip.fs.FsManager.sync(FsManager.java:105)
        at de.schlichtherle.truezip.fs.FsDefaultManager.sync(FsDefaultManager.java:190)
        at de.schlichtherle.truezip.fs.FsSyncShutdownHook$Hook.run(FsSyncShutdownHook.java:93)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: de/schlichtherle/truezip/swing/EnhancedPanel
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:631)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:615)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:141)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:283)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:58)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:197)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
        at de.schlichtherle.truezip.fs.archive.zip.raes.PromptingKeyManagerService.<init>(PromptingKeyManagerService.java:37)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
        at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:355)
        at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:308)
        at java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyIterator.next(ServiceLoader.java:345)
        ... 11 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: de.schlichtherle.truezip.swing.EnhancedPanel
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
        ... 31 more
```

Is it possible to disable TrueZIP key management completely, or at least make sure it doesn't require any Swing components just to extract a ZIP file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With TrueZIP, you have to satisfy the dependency of the TrueZIP Driver ZIP on TrueZIP Swing, or otherwise you won't get rid of this exception. As long as your app doesn't encounter WinZip AES encrypted entries, the key manager popup does not appear. You can also implement your own key management by following this article: http://truezip.java.net/truezip-driver/truezip-driver-zip/key-management.html (but you still need to satisfy this dependency).

Alternatively, you could migrate to [TrueVFS](http://truevfs.java.net). TrueVFS has an even more modular architecture where you could simply add the [TrueCommons KeyManager Disable](http://truecommons.java.net/truecommons-key/truecommons-key-disable/index.html) module on your class path to get the same effect.

Comment: "As long as your app doesn't encounter WinZip AES encrypted entries" -- what if it does, e.g. a user of my *web* application uploads such a file? There is no-one who could ever type into a Swing popup on a Webserver. Is there a way to disable it and instead instantly fail on encrypted archives?

Comment: Also, I cannot use TrueVFS at the moment, because we currently use Java 6.

Comment: Failing with an exception is what the TrueCommons KeyManager Disable does in TrueVFS. Since you can't use it, you'll have to implement your own key management by following the first link, i.e. http://truezip.java.net/truezip-driver/truezip-driver-zip/key-management.html .

Comment: I forgot to mention another alternative which is significantly simpler: You can set the JVM to headless mode - see http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/headless-136834.html . AFAIK this should also disable the Console based key manager and you will simply get an exception.

Comment: OK, thank you. Though this still feels like a hack. Instead of making password manager such an entrenched part of TrueZIP, you could try to make it optional, so that if I don't put JAR with it in my class path, TrueZIP just never uses or ask user for a password.

Comment: Well, it is a plugin architecture. However, it's easier for you to write a custom key manager and plug it into the driver than writing a plugin for TrueZIP. In TrueVFS, there are some ready made key manager plugins, but in TrueZIP this is not available.

Comment: *"it is a plugin architecture"* -- yeah, but how is it a plugin if it is required for TrueZIP to work? A plugin, to me, is something that provides extra functionality, but things work without it too (without this functionality, of course).